# For each div trigger radio button on change via jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, radio-button

I need to check which radio button list is clicked and for the clicked to send a jQuery ajax call, at the moment I have table id plan1, plan2, plan3, generated with php. each has a radio button list, with jQuery each how is it possible to make this happen?

This is what i have done,

```
$("input[name=\'Plan[packageId]\']:radio").change(function () {
alert("changed triggered");
//calculateAmount();
});
```

to make it available for dynamic contents, i can do as below but its not practical since i dont know how many plans will be there.

```
$("#plan1 input[name=\'Plan[packageId]\']:radio").change(function () {
alert("changed triggered");
//calculateAmount();
}); 

$("#plan2 input[name=\'Plan[packageId]\']:radio").change(function () {
alert("changed triggered");
//calculateAmount();
}); 

$("#plan3 input[name=\'Plan[packageId]\']:radio").change(function () {
alert("changed triggered");
//calculateAmount();
});
```

how can i make it dynamic and get current clicked radio button value please

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2nb32s47/4/) is the JS fiddle

```
<table id='plan1'>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>3 Games</lable>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="Plan[packageId]" checked>
            <lable>5 Games</lable>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>10 Games</lable>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
                <br>
<table id='plan2'>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>2 Games</lable
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="Plan[packageId]" checked>
            <lable>4 Games</lable>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>9 Games</lable>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
                <br>
<table id='plan3'>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>4 Games</lable>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="Plan[packageId]" checked>
            <lable>6 Games</lable>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>11 Games</lable>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
var selectedPlan = $("input[name='Plan[packageId]']:checked").val();
alert(selectedPlan);
```

```html
<table id='plan1'>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>3 Games</lable>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="Plan[packageId]" checked>
            <lable>5 Games</lable>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>10 Games</lable>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
                <br>
<table id='plan2'>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>2 Games</lable
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="Plan[packageId]" checked>
            <lable>4 Games</lable>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>9 Games</lable>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
                <br>
<table id='plan3'>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>4 Games</lable>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="Plan[packageId]" checked>
            <lable>6 Games</lable>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="Plan[packageId]">
            <lable>11 Games</lable>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why not just use a class in your table

Comment: what do you want to do by ajax call?

Comment: @Ghost if i use a class, can i get current clicked radio button value ? post your answer with a fiddle please

Comment: @timeman789 if course you can, anyways, check the answer below

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i am doing a calculation with each ajax call, in a nutshell its some payment plans, plan 1, plan 2 plan 3 and can be more plans. each plan says how much to pay based on selected radio button

Comment: @timeman789, please check below answer where you can get clicked button value as well as you can get the id of parent table. You can modify the jquery as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind change event using `.on()` as elements created are dynamic.Use **[start with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** to choose table having id start with `plan` (like plan1, plan2...) and then input with name attribute as shown below

```
$(document).on('change','table[id^=plan] input[name="Plan[packageId]"]', function(){
  //get clicked radio button value
  alert($(this).val());
  //you can find parent table id or any relevant element   
  var table = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    alert(table);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2nb32s47/6/)**

Comment: Please can u update this to get with a class without id such as table[id^=plan] ?

Comment: to use class just replace `table[id^=plan]` with `table.yourClassName`. See [this](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information on jquery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.radioPanle', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2nb32s47/7/

I have applied common class name to each radio button for ease.

You will get value of radio button and pass it to ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your radio groups should be called the same. I mean, all radio options in group 1 should be called "Plan1", then all radio options in group 2 should be called "Plan2" etc.

Finally with these lines you'll able to get your info, and it doesn't matter if you have 3 forms or a hundred forms:

```
$("input:radio").change(function(e) {
    //this will give you the selected value:
    alert ($(this).val());

    //this will tell the radio group where it belongs
    alert ($(this).attr("name"));

    //this will tell the form where it belongs
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    alert($form.attr('name'));
  
    //here you can start your AJAX call or whatever you need
});
```

If you do it like this, users will be able to select one option from every group, however, if you want the user to be able to select only one option from all groups, then you would have to use the same name for all radio buttons, but the code above will still work.

Elements are created "dynamically" but that's PHP's job. Your browser and JQuery doesn't care about that, which means, all elements are loaded in the DOM when your page loads, so they're not dynamic to them.